# Is there a way to uniquely identify players in MC:PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I'm thinking about hosting a small MC:PE server using the [PocketMine](https://www.pocketmine.net/) server platform.

However, I need to be able to uniquely identify players for various purposes. Does MC:PE/PocketMine offer any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think vanilla mcpe does, as you're able to change your username at will. However, you could use a server mod/plugin that makes players register a username with a password, and type the password when they join before being allowed to use commands, build, etc.

**EDIT:** You can use the [SimpleAuth](https://forums.pocketmine.net/plugins/simpleauth.4/) plugin with PocketMine. It "requires registration of player names using a password. That blocks faked usernames and using admin accounts."